# how to start a task in web app

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.net web app on an Azure VM, with an endless loop that processes incoming SMTP email.
I launch the loop from the main form's Load method, but because the loop doesn't return, the Load method never returns, and the page never displays.

How can I easily put the loop in a task that runs asynchronously?

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Threading
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports SendGrid
Imports System.Net

Public Class MAIN_FORM

    Private Sub MAIN_FORM_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        EMAIL_READER.Main()
    End Sub
 . . . . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Load method is only part of form's initialization. Put some controls (like GridView) on the form, and use them to visualize data from EMAIL_HEADER.

```
  Private Sub MAIN_FORM_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    EMAIL_READER.Main()
    GridView1.Datasource = GetData(EMAIL_READER)
End Sub
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.